# Cambio de id en formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

Tengo un formulario donde relleno una serie de campos de una entidad JPA, el caso es que entre los campos hay una lista la cual voy rellenando mediante un modal, hasta ahí todo correcto, de hecho tengo este método hecho para varios controladores y va a la perfección.

El problema está cuando entro a editar la ficha, todo carga correctamente pero cuando le doy al botón Borrar de la lista, al llegar al método del controlador que lo hace, el id del formulario es distinto al que debería, o es -1 o es el número siguiente (cosa que no tiene mucho sentido).

Os dejo la parte del código que puede estar influyendo a ver si alguien ve algo que yo no pude ver.

**Lista**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed flip-content dataTable" th:if="${concert.choirs.size()>0}">
    <thead class="flip-content">
        <tr>
            <th width="90%">
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th width="10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cuerpoTablaCorista">
        <tr th:each="choir,status : ${concert.choirs}">
            <td th:text="${choir.choir.name}"></td>
            <td class="operations"> 
                <a class="delete"  href="/concert/delete_choir/__${status.index}__}" th:href="@{/concert/delete_choir/__${status.index}__}">
                    Borrar
                </a>
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Métodos del controlador**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "concert/delete_choir/{index}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteChoir(@PathVariable String index, @ModelAttribute("concert") ConcertForm concertForm,
            RedirectAttributes ra, Model model) {

        ConcertChoir concertChoir = concertForm.getChoirs().get(Integer.parseInt(index));

    concertForm.getChoirs().remove(Integer.parseInt(index));

    if (null != concertChoir.getId()) {
        basicServ.delete(concertChoir);
    }
    model.addAttribute("concert", concertForm);

    return "redirect:/concert";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/concert", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String concert(@ModelAttribute("concert") ConcertForm concertForm, Model model) {

    model.addAllAttributes(Utils.rellenaCombosConcierto(basicServ));

    model.addAttribute("concert", concertForm);

    return "concert/new";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "concert/edit/{idConcert}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@PathVariable String idConcert, Model model) {

        Concert concert = (Concert) basicServ.findById(Long.valueOf(idConcert), Concert.class);
        ConcertForm concertForm = new ConcertForm(concert);

        model.addAttribute("concert", concertForm);

        return "redirect:/concert";
    }
```

**Formulario**

```
public class ConcertForm extends BaseForm {

    private String name;

    private String date;

    private String act;

    private String notes;

    private Long country;

    private Long province;

    private String provinceName;

    private Long city;

    private String cityName;

    private Long schedule;

    private Long orchestra;

    private Long director;

    private Long composer;

    private Long choir;

    private String choirName;

    private Long soloist;

    private String soloistName;

    private ConcertModalForm concertModal;

    private List<ConcertSoloist> soloists = new ArrayList<ConcertSoloist>();

    private List<ConcertChoir> choirs = new ArrayList<ConcertChoir>();

    public ConcertForm(Concert c) {
        this.id = c.getId();
        this.createDate = c.getCreateDate();
        this.createdBy = c.getCreatedBy();

        this.name = c.getName();
        this.date = Utils.simpleDateToString(c.getDate());
        this.act = c.getAct();
        this.notes = c.getNotes();
        this.country = c.getCountry().getId();
        this.province = c.getProvince().getId();
        this.provinceName = c.getProvince().getName();
        this.city = c.getCity().getId();
        this.cityName = c.getCity().getName();
        this.schedule = c.getSchedule().getId();
        this.director = c.getDirector().getId();
        this.composer = c.getComposer().getId();
        this.orchestra = c.getOrchestra().getId();

        this.choirs.addAll(c.getChoirs());
        this.soloists.addAll(c.getSoloists());
    }
    public Concert getConcert(BasicService bs) {
        Concert c = new Concert();

        c.setId(this.id);
        c.setCreateDate(this.createDate);
        c.setCreatedBy(this.createdBy);

        c.setName(this.name);
        c.setDate(Utils.validaFecha(this.date));
        c.setAct(this.act);
        c.setNotes(this.notes);
        c.setCountry((Country) (null != this.country && this.country != -1 ? bs.findById(this.country, Country.class)
            : null));
        if (null == this.id) {
            c.setProvince((Province) (null != this.province && this.province != -1
                ? bs.findById(this.province, Province.class) : null));
            c.setCity((City) (null != this.city && this.city != -1 ? bs.findById(this.city, City.class) : null));
        } else {
            Concert concertAux = (Concert) bs.findById(this.id, Concert.class);
            if (null == this.province || this.province == -1) {
                c.setProvince(concertAux.getProvince());
            } else {
                c.setProvince((Province) (null != this.province && this.province != -1
                    ? bs.findById(this.province, Province.class) : null));
            }
            if (null == this.city || this.city == -1) {
                c.setCity(concertAux.getCity());
            } else {
                c.setCity((City) (null != this.city && this.city != -1 ? bs.findById(this.city, City.class) : null));

            }
        }
        c.setSchedule((Schedule) (null != this.schedule && this.schedule != -1
            ? bs.findById(this.schedule, Schedule.class) : null));
        c.setDirector((ConcertDirector) (null != this.director && this.director != -1
            ? bs.findById(this.director, ConcertDirector.class) : null));
        c.setComposer((ConcertComposer) (null != this.composer && this.composer != -1
            ? bs.findById(this.composer, ConcertComposer.class) : null));
        c.setOrchestra((Orchestra) (null != this.orchestra && this.orchestra != -1
            ? bs.findById(this.orchestra, Orchestra.class) : null));

        for (ConcertChoir cc : this.choirs) {
             cc.setConcert(c);
        }
        for (ConcertSoloist cs : this.soloists) {
            cs.setConcert(c);
        }
        c.getSoloists().addAll(this.soloists);
        c.getChoirs().addAll(this.choirs);

        return c;
    }


    //getters y setters
}
```

Comment: Puedes poner el html de `status`? entiendo que al request de Java te llega el indice mal, verdad?

Comment: @JordiCastilla acabo de agregar el resto del html de la tabla para que se pueda ver mejor, y si, cuando entra en `deleteChoir` el id de `concertForm` es erroneo (pero antes de eso el id se recupera correctamente, es sólo al pulsar el botón Borrar.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo declaras el bean ConcertForm? ¿Qué scope tiene y cómo obtienes los datos con los que rellenas la lista "choirs"?

Comment: @Pablo Agregados, he de decir que tengo métodos similares en otros controladores de la aplicación y no dan este problema, normalmente introduzco los datos en las listas mediante otro formulario, por ejemplo en este caso para agregar un coro (`Choir`) uso un `Long` porque escojo el coro de entre una lista de ellos guardados en la BD, pero en otras ocasiones donde se requieren mas datos utilizaría un `ChoirForm`, pero en este caso no lo vi necesario, espero que no sea ese el problema...

Comment: ¿qué html genera el caso que te está dando el error?

Comment: @rbernabe ninguna, ya que al intentar cargar de base de datos la entidad correspondiente no encuentra el id correcto y lanza un nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vale, he encontrado el problema.

En el html principal tenia incrustada la siguiente función, que se ejecutaba cada vez que se cargaba la página

```
function cargaCombosLocale(lookupUrl, parentSelectElementId,
        childSelectElementId, isNew) {
    var idSeleccionado = $('#' + parentSelectElementId).val();
    if (idSeleccionado == '-1') {
        if(childSelectElementId === 'provinceField'){
            $("#provinceField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Provincia'
            });
            $("#cityField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Ciudad'
            });
            $('#' + childSelectElementId).prop("readonly", true);
            $('#cityField').prop("readonly", true);
        } if(childSelectElementId === 'cityField'){
            $("#cityField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Ciudad'
            });
            $('#cityField').prop("readonly", true);
        }


    } else {
        $('#' + childSelectElementId).prop("readonly", false);
        if(childSelectElementId === 'provinceField'){
            $("#provinceField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Provincia'
            });
            $("#cityField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Ciudad'
            });
            $('#cityField').prop("readonly", true);
        } 
        if(childSelectElementId === 'cityField'){
            $("#cityField").select2('data', {
                id : '-1',
                text : 'Ciudad'
            });
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : lookupUrl,
        data : {
            id : idSeleccionado,
            isNew : isNew
        },
        success : function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name
                        + '</option>';
            }

            $('#' + childSelectElementId).html(html);
        },
        error : function(request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
    });
}
```

Básicamente es una función que se encarga de cargar los valores de los combos de ciudad y provincia. Los parámetros que se le pasaban eran correctos, lo que no entiendo es porque cambiaba el id. De todas formas se solucionó al sustituirlos por otra función que estaba usando en otro controlador.

Comment: Según lo descrito en tu solución, el problema no está asociado a Java ni a Spring en absoluto. Te recomendaría cambiar las etiquetas de la pregunta a JavaScript y los frameworks relacionados a la generación de la vista.

Comment: Toda la razón, acabo de cambiarlo.

Comment: No debería usarse la función attr de jquery sino prop. Lo edito.